# How to move the x axis to the bottom of a svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis

I am trying to create a barplot using javascript. I have created a barplot, but want to add two axis. Currently stuck on the x-axis.

I am unable to move my x-axis to the bottom of my barplot. I am Using d3 to tailor the svg. I am currently able to showcase it at the top, but want to show it at the bottom.

Any input would be useful!

My attempts  thus far have been to use transform, but when I execute this my axis disappears.

Googled several other solutions, none of them being successful.

Code:

```
<script>

d3.json("data_week3.json", function(data){

    var data_renewables = [];
    var data_nations = [];

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
      data_renewables.push(data[i].Renewable);
      data_nations.push(data[i].Nation)
    }

    var width = 1000,
    height = 500;

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data_renewables)])
        .range([height, 0]);

    var chart = d3.select(".chart")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var barWidth  = width / data_renewables.length;

    var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
        .data(data_renewables)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)"; });

    bar.append("rect")
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d); })
        .attr("width", barWidth - 1);

    bar.append("text")
        .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d); + 3; })
        .attr("dy", ".75em")
        .text(function(d) { return d; });

    var axisScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 30])
        .range([0, 1000]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(axisScale)
        .orient("bottom");

    chart.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

})

</script>
```

Comment: can you provide a working fiddle?

Comment: It may be printing outside the svg space.  Can you check the console log to see if it's being added to the DOM?  You may try adding margins between your chart and the svg boundaries to accommodate the axis and it's labels.

Answer (score 2):

You're giving the chart a height of `height` and then your transform is moving the top of the x axis by a value of `height` so it will always be cut off. I suggest you look at the margin convention: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563